# When can adjectives directly follow prepositions? "to the point of unnoticeable"

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

> I think it's possible for them to fade away **to the point of unnoticeable**.

This is a line I'm writing. "To the point of unnoticeable" just sounds natural enough to me not to bat an eye about it. But on second thought it doesn't seem grammatical. Can adjectives follow prepositions? Grammar rules seem to say no, but there are idiomatic phrases like "**far from complete**" "**far from perfect**". Am I forced to use "to the point of (being/becoming) unnoticeable"?

Some research suggests "to the point of being unnoticeable" seems more common than "to the point of unnoticeable" but I did find this quote from English scholar Richard Dyer:

> ...they also undergo development and combination, sometimes shifting narrative allegiance and... at others reticent to the point of unnoticeable

Comment: It might be that unnoticeable is not a *point*.

Comment: I think I must be confused. Have we somehow gone **from bad to worse** here? The idea that a preposition ever could take an adjective for complement is so **beyond strange** that it leaves me going back and forth **between intrigued and appalled**, then back **to confused** again. :)

Comment: @tchrist Masterfully exemplified.

Comment: For @tchrist ’s examples, insert the elliptical *being* in front of the adjectives (e.g. *from being bad to being worse*). Then do that to yours. *I think it’s possible for them to fade away to the point of being unnoticeable.* I think you’re fine without *being*.

Comment: [UD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=relaxed-to-the-point-of-lazy) ventures 'relaxed to the point of lazy' where one might equate 'to the point of lazy' to ' – lazy, even'.

Answer (score 3):

"To the point of unnoticeable" sounds wrong to me. Confirming this, [Merriam-Webster's examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20the%20point%20of) for the "to the point of" idiom all use it followed by a noun.

Comment: Well, noun or gerund clause. It ᴍɪɢʜᴛ be that *on the point of* is more prone to gerund-clause complements and *to/at the point of* is more prone to non-gerund NPs. Not sure. Both occur with both, but the distribution does not seem similar to me, at least at first glance at the data.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "noun or noun phrase." You can also use a relative clause (e.g. one starting with "where" as a relative adverb) modifying "point," as in "to the point where it became unnoticeable."